# Rails doesn't save nested form with polymorphic models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have these models:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :review, as: :reviewable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :review
end
```

And a form like this:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for(:review, Review.new) do |r| %>
          <%= r.label :content %>
          <%= r.text_field :content %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>

<% end %>
```

Inside my `ArticlesController` I create article simple like this:

```
@article = Article.new(article_params)
@article.save


def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:description, review_attributes: [:id, :content])
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

**Updated:**

**app/models/article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :review, as: :reviewable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :review
end
```

**app/controllers/articles_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article, notice: "Article created!"
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private

def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:description, review_attributes: [:content])
end
```

**view**

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for(:review_attributes, @article.build_review) do |review| %>
    <%= review.label :content %>
    <%= review.text_field :content %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.label :description %>
  <%= form.text_field :description %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's still the same.

Comment: In your form, you need to change `:review` to `:review_attributes`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to require `:id` in your permitted `review_attributes`.